# upgraded to Cosmic, have no audio

Tags: upgrade, sound, 18.10

I upgraded to Cosmic through tonight, and now I have no audio: neither my laptop speakers nor the ehadphone jack seem to do anything. The audio settings menu shows only a "dummy audio" option.

Below are the outputs of `aplay` and `lspci`, which I have seen asked for in the Ubuntu forums (on three year old threads, but whatever).

What can I do to get the sound working? My only idea would be to reinstall  18.04, which worked fine.

```
$ lspci | grep -i audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)

$ aplay -l
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 0: ALC269VC Analog [ALC269VC Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0

$ sudo lshw -C sound
sudo: impossibile risolvere l'host riccardo-laptop: Argomento non valido
  *-multimedia              
       description: Audio device
       product: Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:129 memory:dc228000-dc22bfff memory:dc200000-dc20ffff
```

Comment: My preference for reference material is `sudo lshw -C sound` (list hardware of class=sound), which includes driver= information.  If this looked okay, I'd next explore `pavucontrol` (or pulse audio volume control) esp. the last tab 'configuration' and ensure you have speakers turned on.  I would then turn audio off at last tab, then turn it back on. It may not work, but it's what I'd try first.

Comment: Added the lshw output. The last tab of `pavucontrol` just says "no drive available for configuration"...